# Create a bridge for mobile phone to access desktop LAN network via WIFI

Tags: hotspot, mobile-phone

My mobile phone is unable to connect to LAN network.

I'm trying to get my mobile to access the same network via WIFI.

I was thinking there must be a way to set up mobile hotspot which acts a bridge to access the LAN.

Thanks so much

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. What hardware do you have that has both a LAN and WIFI connection? for example, laptop, Access Point, Router, etc..

Comment: @LPChip the less hardware required the better. 
currently i have my own laptop connected to the LAN network. 
and my mobile which has hotspot capability.

Comment: Do note, receiving hardware, such as mobile phones, mac's and pc's have just one operating way. Either they are a server or a client. This effectively means, if you turn any of your devices into a hotspot, they can no longer be used to access the internet. If your pc or mac is also connected to the network through a LAN cable, then you can setup this device to become a hotspot for the other device. Do note, this pc/mac must have both LAN and WiFi capabilities. Can you also tell us the OS of this device for a proper solution?

Comment: @LPChip Noted. I'm on Windows 10.